# How to get row ( or Range ) by Date in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup, setvalue

I have a google spreadsheet. ( [find here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wfOomeAftjPvLQyfocMxvgL0DnoXCncqwIX13urIi6s/edit?usp=sharing) )

| Date | Name | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | Ajay | 123 |
| 02/01/2023 | Vijay | 158 |
| 03/01/2023 | Rakesh | 258 |
| 04/01/2023 | Baby | 745 |
| 05/01/2023 |  |  |
| 06/01/2023 |  |  |
| 07/01/2023 |  |  |

I want to set values in **B & C columns** where Date is **today** in **Column A** with the values of **B2 & C2**

I have tried this ..

```
function myFunction() {
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() ;
  values = ss.getRangeByName("Sheet1!b2:c2").getDisplayValues() ;
  
  ss.getRange(TodayDatedRow).setValues(values) ;
}
```

I know it will not work. Because TodayDatedRow is not defind.

so how to find the Today dated Row ( or Range ) ..?

Comment: Get all the data and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @TheMaster But I don't know that. Can you give the code pls ?

Comment: Please don't edit in answers in questions. This is not a forum. We have very strict requirements for question posts and answer posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get the row number for the the row containing today's date.

```
function getTodayRow() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let today = new Date();
    // remove time
    today = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate());
    // get the row index
    let index = values.findIndex( row => row[0].valueOf() == today.valueOf() );
    console.log("row index = "+index);
  } 
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
5:55:19 AM  Notice  Execution started
5:55:20 AM  Info    row index = 5
5:55:21 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Which means row 6.

References

- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [Date object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)